# Adding imageViews to next row of table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

in my app i have a table view and i am adding 4 image view to the first row of my table view .Now i want to add the image view to the next row.How can i do that in the existing code please help.I am posting my part of code:--

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIImageView * imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,4,80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView5 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView6 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,4,80, 80)] autorelease];

        int j=0;
        imageView1.tag = j;
        imageView2.tag = j+1;
        imageView3.tag = j+2;
        imageView4.tag = j+3;
        imageView5.tag = j+4;
        imageView6.tag = j+5;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView5];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView6];
}

for ( int i = 1; i <= j; i++ ) {
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];
    imageView.image = nil;
}

int photosInRow;

if ( (indexPath.row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) || ([sentence count] % 4 == 0) ) {
    photosInRow = 4;
} else {
    photosInRow = [sentence count] % 4;
}

for ( int i = 1; i <=[sentence count]; i++ ){
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];
    [self setImage1:imageView];
}

    return cell;
}
```

I want mu imageView 5 and 6 to be in next row.Please help.How to do it?i am ramming my head against the wall looking for this.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try some thing like bellow ... you basically check the present row number then build your required logic ...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];
}

int j=0; imageView1.tag = j;


if(0 == [indexPath row])
{
UIImageView * imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 4, 80, 80)] autorelease];

UIImageView * imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,4,80, 80)] autorelease];

UIImageView * imageView3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];

UIImageView * imageView4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];


imageView2.tag = j+1;

imageView3.tag = j+2;

imageView4.tag = j+3;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];



}else if(0 == [indexPath row])
{
UIImageView * imageView5 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 4, 80, 80)] autorelease];

UIImageView * imageView6 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,4,80, 80)] autorelease];


imageView5.tag = j+1;

imageView6.tag = j+2;



            [cell.contentView addSubview: imageView5];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView6];


}

    for ( int i = 1; i <= j; i++ ) {
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];

    imageView.image = nil;

}
```